# Graph theory: Isomorphic and Complement graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

**- Background Information:**

I am studying discrete mathematics by doing some problems in my textbook. I came across a question that I have a solution for, but I don't understand part of the solution. I need clarification, thanks.

**- Original Question:** Consider part (a)
[image]

**- Chegg solution to part (a):**
[image]

**- My Question:**

Where is division by 4 coming from? Also, is the equation for the number of edges in complement graph of G or both?

Comment: It's the division of $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ by $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the equation for the number of edges in each (i.e. $G$ has $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ edges and the complement has $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$ edges.)

The dividing by four comes from dividing $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ by 2. You know that the sum of the number of edges of $G$ and $G$ complement is the number of edges in the complete graph with $n$ vertices: $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. So 
\begin{align}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}&=(\text{edges in G})+\underbrace{(\text{edges in G complement})}_{\text{=edges in G}}\\
&=(\text{edges in G})+(\text{edges in G})\\
&=2(\text{edges in G}),\end{align}
and dividing both sides by $2$ yields 
\begin{align}\frac{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{4}=(\text{edges in G})=(\text{edges in G complement}).
\end{align}

Comment: Time to change your name to "Useful", perhaps? +1...

Comment: Wow, such a great clarification my friend, @Rohan is right, we will call you Useful :)